# Just sanity-checking a concept... poor man's self-monitored alarm system

Tags: sensors, power, system-design, wireless

If I wanted to throw together a simple burglar-alarm system that had wireless sensors talking to an Arduino (which would then send me an SMS message via cellular shield as a silent alarm telling me which alarm sensor had changed state_)... what technology would you recommend for the sensor-to-arduino signalling?

It needs to be something that draws little or no power until the alarm is triggered, resistant to radio interference, and as always cheap is a huge plus.... but I haven't gotten much beyond that.

(Of course if anyone's already implemented something like this and there are descriptions/sketches I can adopt and adapt, feel free to point me in the right direction.)

EDIT: To provide more info,this is a wood-framed house, 2 storey plus basement, brick chimney possibly in the way. No straight-line distances greater than 60 feet. Wifi, wireless phone, usual electronics and a wood shop I'm still putting together. Shouldn't be difficult, I just want a robust solution in case a friend asks me to replicate it... and for purely aesthetic reasons.

Comment: What sort of range do you need from sensor to Arduino, and what sort of adventure will the transmission signals have - standard house with a few internal walls, big open-plan workshop with near line-of-sight to each sensor, or a shop that sells radio jamming devices that can never be switched off ?

Answer (score 4):

NRF24L01+ for communication. Extreme low power if not sending. Detects packet loss, and automatically resend the packet.

You would however need a small arduino board at the sensor, to read the sensor, and signal to NRF24L01 to send a message.

You'll have to put the arduino in to low power sleep mode to get some good battery life. Either have the sensor wake the arduino up with an interrupt, of poll the sensor like every half second, and immediately go back to sleep.

Comment: That sounds good. See [Power saving techniques for microprocessors](http://www.gammon.com.au/power). For extremely low power you would need switches to wake the Arduino (eg. reed switches on doors and windows).

Comment: extremely low power is only needed if you are running on a coincell or something. The overhead of running a watchdog timer, and waking up once or twice a second, to take a measurement, only means a few less weeks of battery life on e.g. AA batteries (with still more that a year of runtime). Use [this tool to calculate battery life](http://oregonembedded.com/batterycalc.htm) to give you an indication. Sometimes it just isn't worth the effort, just to get a few percent extra battery life.

Comment: It's more than a few percent. You can budget for a current draw of 100 nA with no watchdog timer in full sleep mode, and 6.5 µA with the watchdog timer enabled. So that is 65 **times** the current draw. Now I do indeed have a gadget lying around running from AA batteries that has lasted a couple of years, using the watchdog timer, but it would last even longer if it didn't need to use it.